# Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d2413d.obj'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

i need your advice. i try to display an image with c++ in  visual studio 2013. i installed opencv but i get
Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d2413d.obj'

I know you will tell me that is the path of my image i have changed all the possible ways with the backslashes (), (\), (/)

Comment: Is this compiling opencv itself? If not you messed up your linker settings because opencv is several libraries. You should not be linking `.obj` files instead you need to link `.lib` files.

Answer (score 2):

You must have forgotten to put `.lib` after `opencv_calib3d2413d` in the `linker>input >Additional dependencies` so it should be `opencv_calib3d2413d.lib`.

Comment: Good point. I believe this is the reason. Possibly the windows feature of hiding extensions for known types aided in this problem..

Comment: You don't need an extension there. It will assume the extension for a linker dependency is `.lib`.

Comment: Well , every time i have tried without the .lib ,it throws LNK1104: cannot open file '[filename].obj' ,i'm using VS2015 .